# docker compose exec unexpectly echo non-zero exit code to stderr in Github Actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

Yesterday I migrate my project from TravisCI to Github Actions, with all other code untouched, but never passed then. The cause is that, `docker-compose exec -T container command` unexpectly echo the exit code of command to its stderr, messing my code detecting the stderr.

Here I made a simple [repo](https://github.com/CaptainMorch/compose-problem-reproduction) with only two files to demonstrate the problem:

```
# docker-compose.yaml

version: '3.3'

services:
  test:
    container_name: test
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    command: sleep 100
```

```
# .github/workflows/test.yml

name: test

on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: up
        run: docker-compose up -d
      - run: docker-compose exec -T test false
        continue-on-error: true
      - run: docker-compose exec -T test bash -c "exit 3"
        continue-on-error: true
      - run: echo "stderr $(docker-compose exec -T test false 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
        continue-on-error: true
      - run: echo "stderr $(docker-compose exec -T test false 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
        continue-on-error: true
        shell: bash {0}
```

Excuting these commands on my own machine gives this output:

```
$ docker-compose exec -T test false
$ 

$ docker-compose exec -T test bash -c "exit 3"
$

$ echo "stderr $(docker-compose exec -T test false 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
stderr
```

But here is the log of Github Actions:

```
> Run docker-compose exec -T test false
1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

> Run docker-compose exec -T test bash -c "exit 3"
3
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.

> Run echo "stderr $(docker-compose exec -T test false 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
stderr 1

// the one using bash {0}
> Run echo "stderr $(docker-compose exec -T test false 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
stderr 1
```

So why is those exit codes in my stderr when running in Github Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Found its a feature brought in 1.28.0-rc3, and has been list as an [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8201) to be fixed in 1.28.6.